# pytest patch return type of a method call

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, moto

I want to patch a method return of AWS secrets manager. I am creating a secret and then i am invoking rotate_secret. So once the rotation happens the list_secret call should return a JSON object with a key `NextRotationDate`. Since moto is currently not returning the key my tests are failing.

Here is the code i want to test -

```python
def list(self):
    client: SecretsManagerClient = boto3.client("secretsmanager")
    secrets_list = client.list_secrets(
        Filters=[
            {"Key": "name", "Values": ["test"]},
        ]
    )["SecretList"]

    return secrets_list
```

test.py ->

```python
def test_list(self):
    secret_client = boto3.client("secretsmanager")
    secret_client.create_secret(
        Name="test-secret",
        Tags=[
            {"Key": "id", "Value": "xyz"}
        ],
    )

    secret_client.rotate_secret(
        SecretId="test-secret",
        RotationRules={'AutomaticallyAfterDays': 30},
        RotationLambdaARN=mock_rotation_lambda,
        RotateImmediately=True,
    )

    result = secret_client.list_secrets()
    # I add the NextRotationDate manually here to have the correct result
    result["SecretList"][0]['NextRotationDate'] = datetime(2024, 1, 1)

    with patch.object(secret_client, "list_secrets", return_value=result):
        result = sut.list()
```

Somehow the `list_secrets` is always returning the secret without the needed key. How can i patch it in a way that the `list_secrets` in the test_list return the result i am passing in the patch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Mocking a function from an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134281/python-mocking-a-function-from-an-imported-module)

Comment: unfortunately not. even if i patch the correct namespace like - `with patch("mypy_boto3_secretsmanager.client.SecretsManagerClient.list_secrets", return_value=result):` it still misses the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch botocore to intercept the request, and enrich the response with that particular field.

```py
import boto3
import botocore
from unittest.mock import patch

from moto import mock_ec2


orig = botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call

def mock_make_api_call(self, operation_name, kwarg):
    if operation_name == 'ListSecrets':
        print("Intercepting... ")
        resp = orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)
        # Change the response as appropriate 
        ...
        return resp
    return orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)


def test_list():
    ...

    with patch('botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call', new=mock_make_api_call):
        result = sut.test_list()
```

See the documentation:
https://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/patching_other_services.html

Comment: Tried to implement this but get a weird error - `def _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params):
>       operation_model = self._service_model.operation_model(operation_name)
E       AttributeError: 'TestLambdaHandler' object has no attribute '_service_model'`

Comment: Maybe you can update the original question with the full code, it's difficult to tell what's wrong just based on that error

Comment: Keep in mind that the `mock_make_api_call`-function needs to be at the top-level, not inside a class

Comment: ah yes, that was it. i had it inside my test class. thanks a lot :)

Comment: so since it has to be in the top level, will it not work in a pytest fixture ? i have a text config file where i want to define orig and mock_make_api_call as a fixture

Comment: It can be defined anywhere. As long as the input arguments are correct. If defined inside a class for instance, than then input parameters suddenly become `_mock_make_api_call(self, base_client, operation_name, kwarg)` and you'd need to call `orig(base_client, operation_name, kwarg)`